# Higher-order predicates

Tags: prolog, higher-order-functions, meta-predicate

```
boolean(true).
boolean(false).
formula_0(P, Q):- (P; Q), \+ P.

solution_for_formula(P, Q, Formula):-
    maplist(boolean, [P, Q]), call([Formula, P, Q]).
```

A follow-up to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265727). Why wouldn't this work? (If I replace `call([Formula, P, Q])` with `formula_0(P, Q)` it works.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `call(Formula, P, Q)`, not `call([Formula, P, Q])`. Simply remove the square brackets. Try this to make it more clear what the error is:

```
?- write_canonical(call([Formula, P, Q])).
call('.'(_,'.'(_,'.'(_,[]))))
true.
```

I.e. with the square brackets, you are calling a `(.)/2` predicate, which you (likely) don't define. But the high-order predicate that you want to call is `call/3`, whose arguments are `call(Closure, Arg1, Arg2)`. E.g. `call(formula_0, true, false)` will call `formula_0(true, false)`.

Comment: Thanks! That was actually the first thing I've tired, but the autocompletion played a trick with me, so I've got confused and searched further for different ways to denote a predicate. While searching I encountered a form: `[f, arg0, arg1, ...]`. Would you tell when this form is applicable?

Comment: Likely as argument to the `(=..)/2` standard predicate that allows you to convert between a term and its list representation. E.g. the call `foo(A,1) =.. [foo, A, 1]` is true.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Also, I found the reference, where I've found this form: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Higher_Order_Programming .

Comment: @wvxvw: Could you forward Paulo Moura's comments to this book? It is a pity if there is outdated material on the net.